# Layout for android

Tags: android

I need to have a layout for my widget, but I don't know how to arrage my images on widget screen.

I need to have 4 small Images on first row

then 2 Images on 2nd row

1 Image on 3rd row

and 1 Image on 4th row

Could you please someone create the xml file ?

Comment: Consider rephrase your question. You are not suppose to ask somebody to take over your job.

Comment: I don't consider a little sample as a job, so This is just a sample.

Comment: `I don't consider a little sample as a job, so This is just a sample.` sorry... but wtf? The next time I ask for a state of the art sample of a "swiss army-knife" application/game...

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`TableRow`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html)s within a [`TableLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html).

Refer [Hello TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Using the hierarchyviewer.bat in your sdk|tools folder along the way might be a very good idea as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout(vertical)
    LinearLayout(horizontal)
        ImageView
        ImageView
        ImageView
        ImageView
   LinearLayout(horizontal)
        ImageView
        ImageView
   ImageView
   ImageView
```

Okay?